# Get Typescript type hierarchy as a string

Tags: javascript, typescript, openai-api, large-language-model

```
type Emotion="Excited"|"Disappointed"|"Other"
interface Response{
  summary:Summary
  glossary: Map<string,string[]>
}
interface Summary { 
title:string,
  desc:string,
emotions:Emotion[]
}
hierarchy:string='type Emotion="Excited"|"Disappointed"|"Other";interface Response{  summary:Summary;  glossary: Map<string,string[]>;};interface Summary { title:string;  desc:string;emotions:Emotion[];}'
```

In the above code, can I generate the hierarchy string programmatically.

I am calling LLMS(llama/GPT4) and getting the response as JSON. I send the type hierarchy to ensure type compliance in my response JSON. Currently, I copy paste my Typescript types into the request manually. Is there anyway to obtain the type hierarchy, including all the enums, types and interfaces, as a string programmatically? I would be ok to get is as part of webpack build phase too.